# Deploy external helm chart with Skaffold

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, skaffold

Is there something like [examples/helm-deployment](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/tree/master/examples/helm-deployment) for external helm charts?

Specifically, I'm looking to set up all the monitoring, tracing, etc infrastructure just as in staging/production, on minikube, starting with `stable/prometheus-operator`

Answer (score 0):

I wont be using skaffold for one off deployment of such pods.  Its usually used for those you continuously update and deploy.  Such as your own application.